# Homework help for showing an 'n' number of composite numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program as follows

"Get an integer n from the user; find first n composite numbers; display these number in lines such that each line contains 5 numbers. For example, if the user inputs 10, your program needs to output

4 6 8 9 10

12 14 15 16 18"

The problem is when I type in a number of integers to show, it shows one less than intended, like if I type in '10' for number of integers, it prints out 9 integers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int n;
    int status = 1;
    int num = 1;
    int count = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of composite numbers you wish to view:");

    n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The first " + n + " composite numbers are:");



    for (int i = 2; i <= n;) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(num); j++) {
            if (num % j == 0) {
                status = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (status == 0) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
            i++;
            count++;
        }
        status = 1;
        num++;

        if (count == 5) {
            System.out.println();
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use your debugger to step through the code one line at a time.   You'll find the problem faster and learn more than by asking here.

Comment: It looks like you may be asking for homework help. While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly. (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any specific reason for initialising `i` with `2` in the below loop:

`for (int i = 2; i <= n;) {`

If we initialise `i` with `1`, it seems to be showing 5 numbers per line, e.g.:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n;) {
    for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(num); j++) {
        if (num % j == 0) {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (status == 0) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    status = 1;
    num++;

    if (count == 5) {
        System.out.println();
        count = 0;
    }
}
```